# Stop GraphServiceClient from interpreting text metadata as DateTime

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

My Sharepoint Library has some text columns that sometimes contain date-like text such as `2023-10-21`. In the Sharepoint UI, it correctly displays as a text field with the little Abc icon and in the history the value is displayed correctly as well.
When I read a document's metadata fields with an HTTP request to the graph api with Postman, it simply return that string in the json response.
`"reason": "2023-10-21",`
But when I read a document's metadata fields with the GraphServiceClient like this:

```
var data = await GraphClient.Sites[siteId].Lists[listId].Items[file.ListItem.Id].Fields.GetAsync();
var reason = data.AdditionalData["reason"];
```

The type of `reason` will be either string or DateTime depending on what the column contains. This is bothersome because it is then displayed with .ToString() and the date-like value gets displayed as a date with the default formatting, giving something like this on my machine: "2023-10-21 00 h 00 min 00 s". I can obviously handle that manually but I'd rather not have to check every single text column in case it contains date-like text, or possible even some other type.

Why does the GraphServiceClient do this and can I stop it from doing it?
I understand that as far as JSON serialization is concerned, there's no difference between a string and a date so I really just want to have it deserialized as a string and not as a DateTime.

Comment: Please report the issue in SDK [repository](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues). It can be more complicated